# ngnix - duplicate upstream "app_server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django

Tags: django, nginx

Accidentally deleted conf nginx filled`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django`
 , then filled it with the same configuration settings. got the following error:

```
  Feb 02 12:56:53 solomon nginx[32004]: nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "app_server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.save:1
Feb 02 12:56:53 solomon nginx[32004]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Feb 02 12:56:53 solomon systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 02 12:56:53 solomon sudo[31990]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 02 12:56:53 solomon systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 02 12:56:53 solomon systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 02 12:56:53 solomon systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Configuration, which worked before for sure. Have I done something incorrectly ?:

```
 upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have other configuration files in the directory(`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django`) with same upstream name as 'app_server ' then you get that duplicate upstream error.

So replace 'app_server' to any other name. run `nginx -t` to check for any errors, then restart nginx,

Answer (score 1):

If you tape in your terminal `cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
you will see these two lines:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

> Wich means Nginx load all files `.conf (for example if you are using dokku to deploy your app, you will see dokku.conf which contain "include /home/dokku/*/nginx.conf;" itself)` and this means loading all /home/dokku/whatever-folder/nginx.conf

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the same upstream name "app_server" is not found, find the same upstream name with different case,like:

```
upstream app_server {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000
}
upstream App_server {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000
}
```

This may also cause conflicts. It may be the setting of nginx, but I haven't found the document yet

Answer (score 0):

This problem came up in my case because my configuration file was in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and I also had a symbolic link to it in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. Not sure how `nginx` loads the files but apparently it was loaded twice. No matter what name I chose for the upstream, I got duplicate error. Deleting symbolic link fixed the problem.